# WPF ListView SelectionChanged inside style does not work. EventSetter either

Tags: wpf, listview, selectionchanged

```
<Style x:Key="OrderGroupTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
<Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name.ShowDetailedInfo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2">
                  <StackPanel Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
                     <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=.}" Style="{StaticResource MyRecordViewModelShortStyle}"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Margin="4">                                                                     
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                       <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                          <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ItemsControl_SelectionChanged"/>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I would like to do some job when listview selection changed. because I am using style I cannot use SelectionChanged Event on ListView. I tried to use EventSetter but there is any error while compiling the project:

> The event 'MouseDoubleClick' cannot be
>   specified on a Target tag in a Style.
>   Use an EventSetter instead.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating the Style as a resource instead of declaring it inline.  I don't know why it behaves differently, but it appears to make the error go away:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ItemsControl_SelectionChanged"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OrderGroupTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name.ShowDetailedInfo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2">
                            <StackPanel Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=.}" Style="{StaticResource MyRecordViewModelShortStyle}"/>
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Margin="4" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContainerStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand statement 'because I am using style I cannot use SelectionChanged Event on ListView'

But you can use SelectionChanged event of Listview, if you are using Style also.

Comment: actually I can't. There is a following error when I try to use it:Error 5 The event 'SelectionChanged' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead.

Comment: Try this

<Style x:Key="OrderGroupTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"> 
 <EventSetter Event="ListView.SelectionChanged" Handler="ListView_SelectionChanged"/>
    <Style.Triggers> 
      ...