# The event 'LostFocus' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, .net-3.5

Why am I getting this error message? I'm using an event setter!

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataCell}">
    <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="cellLostFocusHandler" />
</Style>
```

**edit**

I'm not using the style inline. It's in a resource, i.e.:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataCell}">
        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="cellLostFocusHandler" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3139765/302677)

It sounds like you're using the Style inline, instead of as a Resource, and there's issues in setting an EventSetter in an inline style

Comment: I'm not - it is in a resource.

Comment: @Alain Is your DataGrid in a Template, or directly in your Window/UserControl tag?

Comment: It's in a template. The idea here is that I only have to set this event in one place rather than 20 places in my xaml where grids appear.

Comment: I've had the same problem occur with EventSetters nested in Templates. Move your Style out of the template and put it directly under Window.Resources or UserControl.Resources, and then reference it via a StaticResource or DynamicResource in your Template. The property should be something like DataGrid.DataGridCellStyle

Comment: I see. Well crap, how do I apply that style only to items in that template? I'll make a new question for it.

Comment: You should be able to set `<DataGrid CellStyle="{DynamicResource MyStyle}" />`

Comment: Couldn't get rid of this error until I removed the <Style.BasedOn> Tag -  then tadaa...